# Super Puzzle Fighter 2 Turbo HD Remix for the colour blind

Tags: super-puzzle-fighter-2

Super Puzzle Fighter 2 Turbo CD Remix is an enjoyable game, however, for those afflicted with certain types of colour blindness like myself it can prove extremely difficult to play. The green and yellow gems look identical to me, and I can't seem to find an way to change their colour or design to make telling them apart easier, or possible for that matter.

Up to now I've had my friends tell me which blocks are coming down, and then I need to do my best to memorize the locations of the blocks once I've dropped them. In the heat of puzzley battle though, this isn't ideal.
[image]

Is there any other way for me to tell the green and yellow blocks apart, or better yet is their some way for me to either change the block colour or add unique designs for each colour?

Comment: Awww man, that sucks that you're colour blind. I loved puzzle fighter growing up, such a great. I hope you find a solution to this.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the settings on your TV? Does that make it easier to distinguish between the two?

Comment: @Kotsu I'm going to try that now, but you should post that as an answer and not just a comment.

Comment: @Kotsu that worked! So you *definitely* need to post that as an answer now.

Comment: Done. Glad I was able to help you enjoy this wonderful game :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adjusting the settings on your TV. This might make it easier to distinguish between the two colors.

Comment: Hi I know this is an old thread, but could you tell me the settings you used?

Comment: It wasn't me that did it originally, but you could potentially try pushing Contrast **way** up, as this is the thing that affects the "deepness" of colours, for want of a better term. Also, welcome to Arqade! Unfortunately you've posted this in the 'answer' section and it will be removed. If you get 50 reputation points, you'll be able to comment anywhere (you can always comment on your own posts) :)

Comment: It's been a long time, and everry tv is different, but iirc I just turned the colour down, so it became more gray scale, and I was able to tell apart the difference shades of gray. Best idea would be to just play around with the settings until you find something that works.